# View post with specific category id and name which I selected in the backend (drop-down option)

Tags: posts, categories, loop, get-posts, id

I'm trying to get the category ID from Kirki Function and then pass the ID into a loop to get View all posts from that specific category id with name.
I write this code at the backend:

```
Kirki::add_field( 'cactus_option', array(
'type'        => 'select',
'settings'    => 'cat_choose',
'label'       => __( 'This is the label', 'kirki' ),
'description' => __( 'This is the control description', 'kirki' ),
'help'        => __( 'This is some extra help text.', 'kirki' ),
'section'     => 'cat_arrange',
'default'     => 'option-1',
'priority'    => 10,
'choices'     => Kirki_Helper::get_terms( 'category' ),
```

) );

**And I get this result:**

[image]

Now whatever category I have selected, I want to bring its ID on the front page.
And with the help of a loophole from that ID, I want to view all the posts of that Pacific ID.
I have written this code due to which only id number is showing and nothing else.
[image]

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1> <?php echo get_theme_mod('cat_choose', $defaults);?></h1>
</div>
```

**But I want to like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code.

```
<?php $cat_id = get_theme_mod('cat_choose', $defaults); ?>
<p><?php echo get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?></p>
<hr>
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
); 
$cat_posts = new WP_query($args);
if ($cat_posts->have_posts()) : while ($cat_posts->have_posts()) : $cat_posts->the_post(); ?>
<div>
    <div>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

> Display Category Name using Category ID

```
<?php
$cat_id = get_theme_mod('cat_choose', $defaults);
echo get_cat_name( $cat_id );
?>
```

Comment: It's almost done, it's working but the category name not showing.
Edit: Thanks Tanmay Patel

Comment: @AkashManna $cat_id = get_theme_mod('cat_choose', $defaults); using this code, have you got category id??? right???

Comment: Use this code for that <?php echo get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?>

Comment: Hey now its work with this code "<?php echo get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?>" Mr. Tanmay Patel You just awesome.

Comment: Just do accept this answer as green mark because I have updated answer so it can help to other developer for that.